# What kind of tape is used to hold together electronics during shipping?

Tags: mechanical-assembly

Not so fast! This isn't *that* kind of tape (Kapton).

By holding electronics together, I mean to hold mechanical parts together for shipping such as flaps and other parts that can flop such as printers and scanners.

It's a very thick material that holds firm but always comes off easily. I've seen it in a variety of colors such as green, red, but most often in blue.

What kind of tape is this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is it not an *electronic design* question.

Comment: But it does have to do with packaging and shipping of electronics. Do you have a suggestion for a better place to ask?

Comment: I think a very occasional "design for shipping" question is OK esp since this one has a good answer.

Comment: I might have recommended moving this to DIY.SE, but no big deal.

Comment: This is not DIY because it is about packaging small electronics, not stuff to be installed as part of houses or major appliances.

Comment: Do we need an electronicsindustry.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @JeannePindar First rule of creating a new site is that you need a community willing to put forth the effort first.

Comment: This question is really making me want some fruit by the foot

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Probably clean-release/clean-removal strapping tape. Polypropylene with a rubber adhesive.

Eg. 3M [8896](https://www.3m.com/3M/en_US/company-us/all-3m-products/%7E/Scotch-Strapping-Tape-8896/?N=5002385%203293194102%203294334581&rt=rud&DCSext.CDC=AD&DCSext.Business=Safety%20%2526%20Industrial%20Bus%20Group&visitID=31412988534409092570700143750201378068)

[image]

Comment: @jonk Things like the protective film on plastic parts can be challenging to even find the correct search terms for.

Comment: Yes, it's stuff like this that makes a difference in my life. And I appreciate it very much. I don't know exactly when I'll need this. But I know I will at some point. I've logged the information in a place where I can find it when I will need it. Whether for myself or someone else. Thanks. This is the kind of thing like 3M 5200 marine sealant I used to create a strong split-jam for a pocket door that used both steel and wood. It's a fantastic product and the split-jam would otherwise have been a poor strength for the pocket door I built. Rare stuff like this is gold when you need it.

Comment: "I don't know exactly when I'll need this. But I know I will at some point. I've logged the information in a place where I can find it when I will need it." -- My thoughts exactly.

Answer (score 1):

It's called holding tape / blue holding tape / PET blue holding tape.